# Custom Datetime Column In The Products Table Gets Overwritten

Tags: cs-cart

I created a DATETIME column in the cscart_products table and a corresponding input form in update.tpl. 
When I update the products, it works fine the first time. However, if I make a change in other inputs, such as the product name, the value in the DATETIME column I’ve created gets overwritten to 0.

A custom STRING field in the products table does not get overwritten, but only this DATETIME column.
Any idea why this is happening? Thank you in advance.

Below are the codes:

/backend/templates/products/update.tpl

```
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="elm_date_avail_until_holder">{__("available_until")}:</label>
      <div class="controls">
         <div class="ty-calendar" style="position:relative;display:inline-block">
            <input type="text" id="elm_date_avail_until_holder" name="product_data[avail_until]" class="cm-calendar" style="padding-left:24px;width: 105px !important;" value="{if $product_data.avail_until}{$product_data.avail_until|date_format:"`$date_format`"}{/if}" {$extra} size="12" />
               <i class="icon-calendar cm-external-focus" style="position:absolute;top: 6px;left: 6px;"></i>
         </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

/controllers/backend/products.php

in ($mode == ‘m_override’)

```
if (isset($product_data['avail_until'])) {
                $product_data['avail_until'] = $product_data['avail_until'];
            }
```

under

```
if (isset($product_data['avail_since'])) {
                $product_data['avail_since'] = fn_parse_date($product_data['avail_since']);
            }
```

in($mode == ‘m_update’)

```
'avail_until' => 'products_data',
```

under

```
'avail_since' => 'products_data',
```

and

```
elseif ($field == 'avail_until') {
            $desc = 'available_until';
        }
```

under

```
elseif ($field == 'avail_since') {
            $desc = 'available_since';
        }
```

---

**UPDATE**

The date format in  update.tpl

```
{if $settings.Appearance.calendar_date_format == "month_first"}
    {assign var="date_format" value="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"}
{else}
    {assign var="date_format" value="%Y/%m/%d %H:%M"}
{/if}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `update.tpl` template, you're formatting your date by a format that you don't mention: `$date_format`. What is `$date_format`?

So unless `$date_format` produces a date string under this format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`, it will fail to update your DATETIME value properly. 
Also you should validate that the input is valid date.

Comment: I updated my question. You mentioned validating the input that its a valid date. Where can I do this?